# Why Direct I/O requires alignments?

Tags: linux, memory, io

[`man 2 read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) says:

> EINVAL fd is attached to an object which is unsuitable for reading; or
>   the file was opened with the O_DIRECT flag, and either the address
>   specified in buf, the value specified in count, or the current file
>   offset is not suitably aligned.

`Non-direct I/O` has no such limits, but why direct I/O requires alignments?

Answer (score 3):

(Kernel 2.6+) This is because direct I/O *can* be zero-copy from the kernel's perspective (i.e. no more copying takes place in the kernel of the data itself) and disks have a minimum addressable size of I/O known as their "logical block size" (often 512 bytes but might be 4096 bytes or even more). This [O_DIRECT requirement (must obey logical block size alignments) is actually described in the man page for `open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html#NOTES) (see the `O_DIRECT` section under NOTES).

In the buffered I/O case, the kernel copies data out of the userspace addresses and into its own internal page cache address (which obey all the alignment rules and will do read-modify-write if necessary to make sure everything is aligned) and then tells the device to do I/O to/from the page cache locations. In the direct I/O case when everything goes correctly, the memory allocated to your userspace program is the same memory handed to the device to do I/O to/from and thus your program must obey the alignment because there's nothing in between that will fix things up.